# Configure AngularJS Project and Bind Default Views in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I Started a New AngularJS Project, the Configured Project Source Codes are given below. I Can't able to load the Login View even though I specified in **app.run** -> **$location.path('/')**

The HTML Files are

- index.html
- LoginView.html
- HomeView.html

The JS Files are

- app.js
- route.js
- LoginController.js
- HomeController.js

Source Code of index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Login HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Library -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Controller -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="route.js"></script>
    <script src="LoginController.js"></script>
    <script src="HomeController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Login System</h1>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS files are

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $location.path('/');
});
```

route.js

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', { controller: 'LoginController', templateUrl: 'LoginView.html', data: { shouldAuthorize: false } }).
    when('/Home', { controller: 'HomeController', templateUrl: 'HomeView.html', data: { shouldAuthorize: false } })
});
```

LoginController.js

```
app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.messageBox = "Login !";
    $scope.pname = "";
    $scope.pcode = "";

    $scope.LoginAPI = function () {
        alert("Good Attempt !")
        var obj = {
            PName: $scope.pname,
            PCode: $scope.pcode
        };
    };
});
```

HomeController.js

```
app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.messageBox = "Welcome to the Private Area !";
});
```

The HTML Files are

**LoginView.html**

```
<div>
    <h3>Hai, {{messageBox}}</h3>
    <input type="text" value="{{pname}}" /><br />
    <input type="password" value="{{pcode}}" /><br />
    <button onclick="LoginAPI()" />
</div>
```

**HomeView.html**

```
<div>
    <h3>Hai, {{messageBox}}</h3>
</div>
```

I tried to run the application, **I got an error** instead of Loading into the Login Screen

[image]

Kindly assist me, why am getting this error ? By Default I need to load the LoginView.

If I tried to load the URL http://localhost:63627/ then it should load **LoginView**

If I tried to load the URL http://localhost:63627/Home then it should load **HomeView**

Comment: Add the text of the error message URL instead of posting a screenshot; nobody's going to type that out to see exactly what it says. Also, don't bother posting a link if it goes to localhost; we can't use them.

Comment: (Incidentally, if you link to the unminified version of angular during development, you'll get readable error messages instead of the url-encoded nonsense the minified version provides.)